# Definition of Schur Functors on morphisms

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I've been learning about Schur functors on nLab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Schur+functor

A definition is given, for $R$ some finite dimensional representation of $S_n$, by the formula $S_R(-)=R \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[S_n]}(-)^{\otimes n}:\text{FinVec}\rightarrow \text{FinVec}$. I understand how this works on objects, but then the article says that this same formula for $S_R$ works on morphisms too. What is$S_R(f):R\otimes V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow R\otimes W^ {\otimes n}$ supposed to do to the factor $R$? Do they mean to say that $S_R(f)=1\otimes (f)^{\otimes n}?$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.